# Proving that $0v = 0$ for any vector $v \in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that $0v = 0$ for any vector $v \in V$.

---

I'll assume the existence of that $a(b+c) = ab+bc$, $0\times 0 = 0$, $v-v = 0$ and that every vector has an inverse.

$$0v=0$$

$$0v+(-0v) = -0v$$

$$0(v-v) = 0\times 0 = 0 = -0v $$

Similarly,

$$-0v = 0$$

$$-0v + 0v = 0v$$

$$0(-v+v) = 0\times 0 = 0 = 0v$$

I'm not quite sure if it would be fine to assume the existence of the properties I used in this proof.

Comment: If your goal is to *prove* that $0v=0$, you can't start from that.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are assuming that $0v=0$ to prove that $0v=0$, which is a circular reasoning and proves nothing.

The trick is:
$$0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v$$
Then add $-(0v)$ and you get
$$0=0v$$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I think I'll need more practice with proof-writing.